# Change image based on dropdown using javascript.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, select

I am a beginer in javascript and I want to change an image based upon options in my dropdown (select) 
I find this [tutorial](http://www.flowsim.se/picts/iljjava/eiljsele.html), but I am having some problems.

In this tutorial they replace iljbild by the name of the picture files you are going to use
if you want to use the code as it is the names of the picture files have got to be of the same type as in the example, ie the only thing telling the files apart should be a number, e g pict0.gif, pict2.gif etc.
if you are using jpg images you will have to replace gif by jpg.
set the WIDTH and the HEIGHT of the images
if you change the (length of the) words in the selection list you will also have to change the number after charAt (here it is 8)

it's what i did by replacing iljbid by:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please show us some code...

Comment: Hello, this is very easy to do with Javascript, but you must put some code for us to help you...

And, by the way, you put jquery as a Tag, but in the example there's no jquery at all... it's just plain Javascript

Comment: the site you're reading this tricks is really poor. There are amazing resources on how to achieve the desired. Guess one. Exactly, StackOverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/VYbLX/)**

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" />
<select id="picDD">
    <option value="1" selected>Picute 1</option>
    <option value="2">Picute 2</option>
    <option value="3">Picute 3</option>
    <option value="4">Picute 4</option>
    <option value="5">Picute 5</option>
</select>
```

---

```
var pictureList = [
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1",
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2",
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3",
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4",
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5", ];

$('#picDD').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
    $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
});
```

Comment: This won't work properly, since you begin to count at 1 when a table first row is 0.
You should either put the options values form 0 to 4 or make a -1 on the val variable in javascript.

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial expect you to have a list of images with a named convention. That is {prefix}{number}.{extension}. For exmaple:
image0.jpg
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
and so on...

The prefix on all images must be the same, and the extension on all images must be the same. This is a simple tutorial to get the effect done.

It can be expanded once you have more JavaScript knowledge.

Also, that tutorial is really bad (don't mean to disrespect, but it is really lacking. Copying and pasting the example itself into JSFiddle throws errors everywhere).

The tutorial is from 1998. That is 16 years old. I strongly suggest you to look for newer tutorials. (2010+)

Here is an example replica of the tutorial that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/VmWD9/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://www.flowsim.se/picts/selec01.jpg" width="70" height="70" name="myImage" />
<form method="" action="" name="myForm">
    <select size="8" name="switch" onchange="switchImage();">
        <option value="1">Image 1</option>
        <option value="2">Image 2</option>
        <option value="3">Image 3</option>
        <option value="4">Image 4</option>
        <option value="5">Image 5</option>
        <option value="6">Image 6</option>
        <option value="7">Image 7</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// This is the code to preload the images
var imageList = Array();
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    imageList[i] = new Image(70, 70);
    imageList[i].src = "http://www.flowsim.se/picts/selec0" + i + ".jpg";
}

function switchImage() {
    var selectedImage = document.myForm.switch.options[document.myForm.switch.selectedIndex].value;
    document.myImage.src = imageList[selectedImage].src;
}
```

Though nowadays people use JavaScript libraries such as jQuery or MooTools to acomplish things like that. I do find that it is better to first explore things in pure JS before heading into these libraries, though it is not a necessity. Most of these libraries are easy to grasp, but when you want to make something big you might need to have prior JS knowledge.

I recommend that you go through the [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve the desired.

[This one](http://jsbin.com/womufu/1/edit) is by getting the Number `value` after the select `change` event and get that `src` out of the `imagesArray` Array key.

```
<select id="changeImage">
  <option value="0">image 0</option>
  <option value="1">image 1</option>
  <option value="2">image 2</option>
</select>
<img id="image" src='//placehold.it/50x50/cf5'>
```

```
var imagesArray = [
  "//placehold.it/50x50/cf5", // represents val 0,
  "//placehold.it/50x50/f1f", // 1,
  "//placehold.it/50x50/444"  // 2 ...
];

$('#changeImage').change(function(){
  $('#image')[0].src = imagesArray[this.value];
});
```

[The other one](http://jsbin.com/womufu/2/edit) is to have image names inside the `option` text:

```
<select id="changeImage">
  <option>image.jpg</option>
  <option>something.png</option>
  <option>nature.jpg</option>
</select>
<img id="image" src='image.jpg'>
```

```
$('#changeImage').change(function(){
  $('#image')[0].src = this.value;
});
```