# Link image to a value in a drop down list

Tags: html, css

I currently have a drop down list with a few values in it, I was wondering if it is possible to have a image next to the drop down list that changes corresponding to the value in the drop down list?
This the code for my drop down list. If you need anymore information please ask.

```
<form id="formddl">
            <a id="infoheader">GreenB Colour</a> <br><br>
            <div class="header">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">Ivory White</option>
                    <option value="1">Carbon Black</option>
                </select>
            </div>   <br><br>       

            <script src="fancystyle1/js/jquery.simple.select.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('select').selectBoxes();  
                });             
            </script>
        </form>
```

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254608/change-image-based-on-dropdown-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks! that should help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("#iama").children().click(function changeImage(){
var value = $("#iama option:selected").val();
  if (value == 1){
  
  $("#image").attr("src","http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
  }
  else {
    $("#image").attr("src","http://lorempixel.com/600/200/");
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="iama">
  <option value=1>image for value 1</option>
  <option value=2>image for another value</option>
</select>
<img id ="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
```