# Changing image on dropdown javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replicate [this simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22255255/4497863) but for the life of me cannot get it to work. The first picture displays, but it doesn't ever change. Forgive me if this is basic, I am pretty new with javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pictureList = [
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4",
        "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5", ];

    $('#picDD').change(function () {
        var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
        $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" />
    <select id="picDD">
        <option value="1" selected>Picute 1</option>
        <option value="2">Picute 2</option>
        <option value="3">Picute 3</option>
        <option value="4">Picute 4</option>
        <option value="5">Picute 5</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place your code in :

```
 // A $( document ).ready() block.
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    // Your code here.
 });
```

Else your code wont work. In jsfiddle you can see on the left the javascript is loaded onDomready

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#picDD').change(function () {
        var val = parseInt($('#picDD').val());
        $('img').attr("src",pictureList[val]);
    });
});
```

In the jsFiddle, you don't have to specify the document ready function as it is done dynamically. Try this, it should work for you.