# Picture Change in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well this doesn't worked for me and idk what to do so I ask you guys hopefully you can help me. Script is at the top, in the middle I add picture with id and I want to apply the change on a button below.

```js
function pictureChange()
    {
    document.getElementById("theImage").src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6dc68b9b-62ee-49bb-904f-9bc85ead27a3%2Fhn%C4%9Bd%C3%A1-2.jpg?1539113123667";
    }
```

```html
<div style="padding-top:2%;padding-left:42.7%" class="row">
  <img id="theImage" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6dc68b9b-62ee-49bb-904f-9bc85ead27a3%2Fhn%C4%9Bd%C3%A1-2.jpg?1539091308847" style="width:300px;height:240px">
</div>


<center>
 <div class="btn-group" style="padding-top:1%">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="pictureChange()">Vyberte barvu</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle px-3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hnědá</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lakované dřevo</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Olej černá</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Olej bílá</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Šedá</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Světle hnědá</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Teak</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Zelená</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</center>
```

Comment: What errors occur? What doesn't happen that you expect to happen?

Comment: it would be helpful if you mentioned any console.log errors or otherwise included your code as a runnable example

Comment: And it actually for me here. what are you trying to do? https://plnkr.co/edit/DBokfqQ6ERqjUdpwuWLR?p=preview

Comment: Well nothing happens in console. I want it to replace a picture on the button click

Comment: if you remove src from html and click the button, you will see that it does add the image. as per plunker link above

Comment: Why toggle drop down with button? why not just use a drop down? Also, these do not appear to be URLs to other photos.

Comment: Your code works fine, but you put the Javascript in the CSS box, so your snippet won't work. I notice the two images are exactly the same, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The new image src is a different image, but it looks exactly the same so you can't tell that it has changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image based on dropdown using javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254608/change-image-based-on-dropdown-using-javascript)

Comment: @DanielWilliams hah, no that was my fault when I threw his code into the snippet editor apparently hastily between builds and distracted, good catch :D

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change it to the same picture as it was. It's actually working you can't just see it.